# How to use lambda to for boost asio async completion handler

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, bind, boost-asio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print(boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* count)
{
    if (*count < 5)
    {
        std::cout << *count << "\n";
        ++(*count);

        t->expires_at(t->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        t->async_wait(boost::bind(print, t, count));
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;

    int count = 0;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
//    t.async_wait(boost::bind(print, &t, &count));
    t.async_wait([&]{ // compile error occurred
        print(&t, &count);
    });

    io.run();

    std::cout << "Final count is " << count << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

> What's the different between bind and lambda exp.? I guess it's OK in syntax, the problem is async_wait need a function object with param "const boost::system::error_code& e".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know asio very well, but adding the requested parameter fixes the issue.

```
t.async_wait([&] ( const boost::system::error_code& ) {
    print(&t, &count);
});
```

It looks like a quirk or bug of Boost.Bind allows additional, ignored arguments to a bind expression generated from a function pointer. It's probably better not to rely on this, but to explicitly accept and discard the error code.

Comment: It's weired in boost::bind and std::bind works fine, could it be said that boost::bind or std::bind return a function object with param "const error_code&"? but obviously std::bind is not associated with boost::system::error_code.

Comment: @met7 They must be generically ignoring any passed argument, of `error_code` or any other type. I'm surprised std::bind is doing that; I'll look into it later.

Comment: Boost.Bind specifies that "[any extra arguments are silently ignored](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions)."  It is not as explicit in the standard, but I believe func.bind.bind permits the behavior when it states that `INVOKE(fn, t1, ..., tN)` must be a valid expression for _some_ values `w1, w2, ..., wN`.

Comment: @TannerSansbury But, that Boost "feature" does not apply to bind objects generated from functors or PTMFs. No, that is not implied by that standard text; the number of values passed is specifically N and not some M ≤ N.

Comment: @Potatoswatter When I check that error_code it is always set to: Operation canceled. Does that mean something is wrong or should I not check that error_code at all?